# How to mark has_one/has_many association as dirty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been looking for this kind of functionality in AR, but don't seem able to find it. The Dirty implementation of AR states that an already persisted instance is deemed only dirty if one of its direct attributes has changed. So, let's say:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_one :frame
end
```

in this case, I can do something like:

```
p = Picture.new(:gallery => Gallery.new, :frame => Frame.new)
p.save #=> it will save the three instances
p.gallery = Gallery.new
p.save #=> will not save the new gallery
p.gallery_id_will_change!
p.gallery = Gallery.new
p.save #=> this will save the new Gallery
```

but now I can't do something similar for the has_one association, since the Picture implementation doesn't own an attribute referring to it. So, it seems such dirty markups are impossible. Or aren't they?

Comment: Dirty flags are set for attributes on the model itself, not for related objects.  It only works for the `belongs_to` because there is a foreign key on the model.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of what you can do. I'm just questioning why can't you also "dirty" the other associations, given the requirement. It's clear that what it already exists is a good default, but if one would like to save associations (not belongs_to), then one doesn't have an alternative besides saving the association explicitly.

Comment: Do you understand that a belongs_to implies that there is a column on the table which can be set to dirty?  Other relationships do not possess a column on the table, but rather on other tables.

Comment: yes, I understand, and that is what i meant by "yes, I'm aware of what you can do"! So, I'll repeat: wouldn't it be great to mark the association (NOT the column) as dirty, so that the business logic could take that into account while persisting the model into the database? What you said is that DB columns are marked as dirty, but this logic belongs to the model. I am aware that the current implementation only marks specific attributes to the model (foreign key as well, therefore belongs_to) as dirty, I'm just questioning whether it would be a good idea to extend that.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I can figure out to do is:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_one :frame

  after_save :force_save_frame

  def force_save_frame
    frame.save! if frame.changed?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [weexpectedTHIS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792445/weexpectedthis) said Dirty flags are set for attributes on the model itself, not for related objects. It only works for the belongs_to because there is a foreign key on the model.

But you can make a trick like that

```
module FrameDirtyStateTracking
  def frame=(frame)
    attribute_will_change!('frame')
    super
  end
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  prepend FrameDirtyStateTracking

  belongs_to :gallery
  has_one :frame
end

picture = Picture.new
picture.frame = Frame.new
picture.changed? # => true
picture.changed # => ['frame']
```

Comment: any drawbacks or something that might gone wrong with this?

Comment: I don't think so @ted but obviously is hard to figure out all cases and mainly edge cases.